# Can't escape grub after Fedora 33 update

Tags: linux, fedora, grub2, grub

Got Fedora & Win10 dual boot for 2 years now. I've recently updated Fedora and since then I can't boot either of the systems and can't really escape grub. Tried countless youtube/forum ideas, none worked for me.
The whole process of:

```
set root=(hdX, Y)
set prefix=(hdX, Y)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

did not work for me with any of the partitions.
The only partitions wit ext2 are hd0,gpt5 & lvm/fedora...-root (photo)

[image]

Some people told me to find grub directory with i386-pc in it, luckily I did (photo), but none of their further advises helped.

Will be really glad for any piece of advice beacuse I really feel like I've tried everything I could find on the topic & feel so desperate now :c

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
linux (hdX,Y)/boot/vmlinuz-... root=/dev/sd..
initrd (hdX,Y)/boot/initrd-...
boot
```

Use autocomplete to select which `vmlinuz-...` and `initrd-...` you can boot.
`/dev/sd..` will be the corresponding disk and partition, if `(hd0,gpt2)` for example, then `/dev/sda2`.